# Work by team with git on localhost

Tags: wordpress, git, version-control, localhost, wordpress-theming

I am a beginner to this topic and I start developing a part of the special theme on wamp (localhost) and another teammate work on the remaining part.In this regard, think that I should use Git but I do not know what folders (wamp and wp and theme and plugin) put in the repository and which client of git is more suitable for us (all of us do not have much knowledge and little time to do it). please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anything that needs installation keep it outside of git.
any file which is specific to your machine and local settings , keep t in `.gitignore`
all the files and folders that are required to setup the project in any new machine + any files that would be changed by your teammates , include in the `git`.

ideally, the `git init` should be done in the project root. ou can make a branch for every theme and merge later when finished.

Answer (score 0):

I'd initialize GIT in the root directory of the template itself since you only make changes *in* that specific folder. 
In this case, each template/theme can be considered as one single GIT repository.

Hope this answers your question.